# How can I input a fasta file and a text file together using command line argument

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I have a fasta file and a text file and I want to use command line argument to input my files using python.

I want to use something like:

```
python3 myprogram.py --fasta_file test_seq.fasta --enzyme_file enzymes.fasta
```

Comment: Do you just want to read in the arguments (e.g. ``fasta_file="test_seq.fasta"``) or actually do something with them?

Comment: Is this question in any way specific to fasta? Or can the question be rewritten to "How can I read command-line arguments with python?"

Answer (score 3):

You need to use argparse, but I strongly suggest you to read the tutorial first (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html).

A possible solution to what you are asking is the following:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--fasta_file")
parser.add_argument("--enzyme_file")

args=parser.parse_args()
with open(args.fasta_file, "r") as f:
fasta_data = f.readlines()

with open(args.enzyme_file,"r") as f:
enzyme_data=f.readlines()
```

Comment: It is idiomatic to use ``with`` context managers instead of ``open``/``close``. Context managers require less code and are more robust to failures.

Comment: Thank you.  I corrected the code.  Although the focus should be in the argparse.